# Minimax Alpha Beta Pruning vs Suboptimal Opponent

Tags: algorithm, search, minimax, game-theory

Within the game of chess, if I have an AI agent that uses minimax with alpha beta pruning against an opponent that selects random, often sub-optimal (but legal) moves, would minimax still be optimal? What would happen if the opponent made a sub-optimal move that was in one of the subtrees that was pruned?

Comment: Alpha beta pruning will never change the result of minimax, it just prunes branches that can not have better moves. And a minor comment: we can call minimax's result optimal only if we visit the whole tree to the leafs, unless all results should be considered as sub-optimal.

Comment: The pruned branches are never interesting, because the algorithm already found a better variant at an upper level in the search tree. This would remain true if the opponent would not play the best move. Both minimax & alphabeta assume the worst case, which is when then opponent plays the best move. Of course, if you would be *absolutely* sure that the opponent will not play the best move, you could sometimes get a better position by playing differently, but this you cannot really call "optimal" play, as in practice you *don't* know what an opponent will play in some future.